# Odoo 10 - QWeb Barcode generator, EAN13 missing leading zero

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have a product with the following barcode, which can be accessed in the QWeb report as `o.barcode`:

```
0200000100094
```

I use the following syntax to generate the barcode in a QWeb report:

```xml
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('EAN13', o.barcode, 500, 250)" />
```

However, Odoo QWeb prints barcode with 12 digits, i.e. it prints:

```
200000100094
```

I guess somehow `o.barcode` is being identified as a number and hence the leading zero is being removed.

How can I preserve the leading zero while printing/displaying the EAN13 barcode in Odoo?

Answer (score 1):

Add this python function to your barcode report.

```
<t t-if="o.barcode">
    <span t-esc="(o.barcode).zfill(13)" style="float:left;margin-left:25px !important;"/>
</t>
```

For more refer this [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill).